# Search 'Hangs' While Trying to Assign Transactions to a Batch

Tags: civicontribute

I created a Smart Group of members whose memberships are expiring in a particular month.  I then created a new accounting batch.  When I open the batch by clicking 'Transactions,' I get a list of all 2,000 plus members.  Then I tried to revise my search by selecting the Smart Group in the search screen.  When I click search, I get a small box in the middle of the screen that says 'Processing...'  However, nothing happens. It appears that CiviCRM is hanging. I can find no reference to anything similar happening in any of the CiviCRM sites.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen for many reason

- check for any error message in Civicrm Log file
- check for any error message in PHP error log file

If you haven't got any error message then

- your MySQL DB is old version and you need to upgrade to latest 
   Because some SQL which has been written in MySQL 5.6 is not been supported in Mysql 5.1 - which will not return any value and will timeout
- also check for your Php Version too